# SOLR mass delete by URL

Tags: solr

SOLR index contains 3,5 million URLs. I have a list of 1,5 million of "proper" URLs (no template, just a random list).

How can I delete 2 million of URLs from SOLR index (I need to search on my 1,5M URLs only)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can not distinguish between "proper" documents and the rest by a criteria that can be translated in a delete query, you are better with reindexing the 1.5 million, assuming that you have all the data to recreate the documents.

Comment: I have a list of URLs that I want to index (1,5million). This set of ulrs belongs to the big URLs set (3,5 million) - already crawled, parsed and indexed data. Yes, I could re-crawl these 1,5M URLs. But may be another solution exist? Something like EXCEPT SQL operator? Or I should 1) get all URLs in SOLR index(is it possible?) 2) define URLs for deletion 3) create a program to iterate thru delete list and call something like SOLR.deleteByURL(url) ?

Comment: Are you sure there is not a single criteria by which these documents 
can be selected for deletion? If not just group the delete by id  requests in reasonable size batches. Take a look http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#A.22delete.22_documents_by_ID_and_by_Query and then just commit once in a while also run a optimize when the process is done

Comment: Yes,100% sure that there is no a single criteria.